# JavaFX Properly Closing a Popup

Tags: javafx, popup

So I am just wondering if anyone knows the correct way to close a popup in JavaFX 8. For example if I have a cancel button on my popup what method should I use to get rid of the popup when the cancel button is pressed? I am currently just using the hide() method. This scares me a little bit because I am not sure if the popup is lingering in the background somewhere and still needs to closed. However, when I look at the java docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Popup.html) I don't see any close() method, I also don't see a close() method in my IDE autocomplete. I do see onCloseRequest() and such in the docs though, so I guess my real question is this; does the hide() method close the popup? If not what does? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `hide()` is enough.

Also make sure you don't store any reference to the Popup once you don't need it anymore, so that it can be garbage collected.